# Undocumented WolframLibraryData::evaluateExpression

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, undocumented, librarylink

It seem there's this promising function in the callback object provided to MathLink C functions:

```
struct st_WolframLibraryData
{
    /* ... */
    int (*evaluateExpression)(WolframLibraryData, char *, int, mint, void *);
    /* ... */
};
```

If this does what it seems it does, it would save the boring and lengthy code that comes with managing a `MLINK` object for some purpose. But I'm lost at interpreting the arguments (and if the second one is supposedly the string to execute, why is it not `const`?).

Comment: The internal structure of a parsed expression is more like an `Internal\`Bag`, not a string. So I wouldn't like to guess what kind of inputs this thing requires.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have done a brief reverse engineering, and this is the result.

Here's how to interpret the function:

```c
int // 0 = LIBRARY_NO_ERROR for success, 6 = LIBRARY_FUNCTION_ERROR for bad syntax
evaluateExpression(WolframLibraryData _ignored, char* expression, int ResultType, mint ResultStuff1, void* ResultStuff2);
```

So the problem is that the function tries to store the result of the expression in some internal format using the last two arguments... **unless** `ResultType == 6`.

So, this wrapper comes handy if you want to evaluate some hardcoded expressions in your C library:

```c
int MathematicaEval(WolframLibraryData wd, const char* expression){
    return wd->evaluateExpression(0, (char*)(expression), 6, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Result type = 6 means a "normal expression", a  compound non-atomic expression (like "Plus[a, 2]").